# Is there a way to add surface points/particles on the faces and not just vertices of a 3D .OBJ file on Three JS?

Tags: three.js

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        // load a resource
        loader.load(
            // resource URL
            'public/_resources/themes/webgl/images/Horse.obj',
            // called when resource is loaded
            function(object) {
                object.traverse(function(child) {
                    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

                        var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
                            color: 0x000000
                        });

                        var points = new THREE.Points(child.geometry, material);
                        scene.add(points)
                    }
                });
                scene.add(object);

            },
```

The above code adds to the vertices only, is there a way to add thousands of them on the Horse.obj **SURFACE**? It is using BufferGeometry. Kindly let me know thank you. 
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=scatter#webgl_instancing_scatter, you'll find `MeshSurfaceSampler.js` there.

Comment: Thank you @prisoner849, unfortunately I am abit new to three js I am not able to understand that example, as its taking a gltf object as a point on another object, as well as how mesh sampling is working, would there be a simple example if possible?

Comment: Used it here: https://codepen.io/prisoner849/pen/YzPWGRY?editors=0010 lines 81-94 in `js` section of the codepen.

Comment: Thank you very very very very much :) @prisoner849